# Wordpress suspicious access

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, monitor

I have activated a 404 Monitor in wordpress and I have several suspicious URI entrys like:

https://example.com/vpn/hello (40 times)

https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-time-capsule/readme.txt (6 times)

https://example.com/MAPI/API (2 times)

https://example.com/downloader (5 times)

https://example.com/owa/auth/logon.aspx (1 time)

and a lot more...

> Where all this attemps came from? is someone trying to hack my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very likely someone is trying to do a malicious activity on the Wordpress site.

I would recommend you Install and Configure good security plugin like "iThemeSecurity"

It will block such attacks and it will also ban IPs where requests are coming from.

I hope that helps. Thanks.